# Show if a graph can be written as Cartesian product

Tags: graph-theory

I am asked to prove if the following graph can be written as Cartesian product of two graph in a non-trivial way.

[image: Graph]

I know the answer is no is because it is kind of a symmetric graph so that it can not divided into two graph. But are there any ways i can prove this?

Thanks

Comment: Please include definition of Cartesian graph.

Comment: @coffeemath, Cartesian product, is a standard elementary set theory term.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Your graph can be redrawn as

[image]